# C# Check List against part of string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which contains values such as:

- readies action
- uses action
- begins to cast action

I want to compare a string to match against this list and return a boolean based on that. So for example:

```
string compare = "The Manipulator uses action";
```

To do this I have tried two different methods, the first being:

```
if (mylist.Contains(compare)) { //True }
```

and the second (with Linq):

```
if (mylist.Any(str => str.Contains(compare))) { //True }
```

The problem I'm having is both of these methods match against an extended string. What I mean by that is if **compare == "uses action"** the statement returns true, but if **compare == "The Manipulator uses action"** the statement returns false.

Any help on fixing this would be most appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally following what you're looking for, so there are 2 different solutions, besed on expected outcome.

If you're only trying to match exactly the same string from within the list `Any` is the way to go, but you should use `==` instead of `Contains`:

```
if (mylist.Any(str => str == compare)) { //True }
```

If you'd like extended string to also match, you use `Contains`, but instead of calling `str.Contains(compare)` call `compare.Contains(str)`:

```
if (mylist.Any(str => compare.Contains(str))) { //True }
```

Comment: Excellent.

if (mylist.Any(str => compare.Contains(str))) { //True }

does what I was looking for! Thanks so much.

Comment: @user1772824 If the answer is what you are looking for, you should accept it.